# Merge Tables with Remainders - Lua

Tags: lua

What I have is a nested table (two-levels). What I'm looking to do is merge (flatten?) the sub-tables, with any duplicates spilling over into new keys.
So the input would look like

```
t = {
  [1]  = {
    [1] = "One",
    [3] = "Three"
  },
  [2] = {
    [2] = "Two",
    [3] = "Three"
  },
  [3] = {
    [1] = "One",
    [2] = "Two",
    [4] = "Four"
  }
}
```

and the output would look like

```
t = {
  [1] = {
    [1] = "One",
    [2] = "Two",
    [3] = "Three",
    [4] = "Four"
  }  
  [2] = {
    [1] = "One",
    [2] = "Two",
    [3] = "Three"
  }
}
```

The input table would be up to 1000 keys, so I'm hoping it can be done efficiently.

Comment: Will tab[1] be the same for every table where it's present? Could there be a table where ```[1] = "Four"```?

Comment: Yes, the values were just for example. The keys will always be 1-4, but the values will often be of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local bottom, max_btm = {}, 0
for top = #t, 1, -1 do
  for k, v in pairs(t[top]) do
    local btm = bottom[k] or 0
    if btm < top then
      repeat btm = btm + 1
      until btm == top or not t[btm][k]
      if btm ~= top then
        t[btm][k], t[top][k] = v
      end
      bottom[k] = btm
      max_btm = math.max(max_btm, btm)
    end
  end
  if max_btm < top then
    t[top] = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
local d={}
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if k~=1 then
        for kk,vv in pairs(v) do
            if t[1][kk]==nil then
                t[1][kk]=vv
            else
                d[kk]=vv
            end
        end
        t[k]=nil
    end
end
t[2]=d
```

Comment: How does it work with large amounts of remainders? For example, say there's two remainders of [2] = "Two"

Comment: @user142532, the code above only keeps one copy of each duplicate, If that does not suit you, you'll have to specify your problem more precisely.